# Wronskian, Linear Dependence and Construction of ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I already understand that for second-order, linear, homogeneous ODE, if the Wronskian of two solutions to the ODE ( or functions that satisfy the ODE) is zero at a certain point, the functions are linearly dependent.

At another place (source at bottom), it has been written that if Wronskian is zero at a certain point, it is not necessary that they are linearly dependent. As an example,

> for f(x) = x, g(x) = sin(x), we find W(f, g) = x cos(x) − sin(x) which is
> nonzero, for example, at x = π. Hence, x and sin(x) are Linearly
> Independent. Note that W(f, g) may be zero at some point such as x =
> 0.

The only way I can resolve these two statements is by saying that you can't construct a second-order, linear, homogeneous ODE which has these two functions, x and sin(x) as it's solutions (i.e. they satisfy the ODE).

I don't know how to formally prove this, except that I observe that sin(x) already is the solution of second-order, linear, homogeneous ODE, of which x is not a solution, so adding it might make a third-order or say non-linear ODE.

So, how do we actually resolve these statements and can we prove that we can't construct an ODE as required above?

**EDIT:** This question was solved earlier, but I have a doubt in the solution by mathcounterexamples.net now: why can we not change the coefficient of y'' to the function in the denominator (xcos(x) - sin(x)) ?

Source: [https://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode7.pdf](https://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Esghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode7.pdf) or
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGRE00YNB0kjVHam9ZSpsDQfba0PxkYG/view?usp=sharing

---

Relevant statement:

> **Theorem 3:** Two solutions $y_1,y_2$ of
> $$
> y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0, \quad x \in \mathcal I
> $$
> are linearly dependent iff $W(y_1,y_2) = 0$ at a certain point $x_0 \in \mathcal I$.

Comment: The first paragraph you wrote is confusing. It would be clearer if you wrote "if the Wronskian of two **solutions to this ODE** (or **functions that satisfy the ODE**) is zero at a certain point, the functions are linearly dependent." Similarly, in your fourth paragraph, it's not immediately clear what you mean by an "ODE of these two functions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Take $a,b$ real maps to define any required second-order, linear, homogeneous, ODE

$$y^{\prime \prime}(x) =a(x)y^\prime(x) +b(x)y(x)$$

and deduce a contradiction if $x, \sin x$ are both solutions.

Indeed, $x$ solution implies $a(x)=-xb(x)$. While if $\sin x $ is a solution

$$-\sin x =- x \cos x b(x)+ \sin x b(x)$$

and

$$b(x)=\frac{\sin x}{-\sin x + x \cos x}$$ which is not continuous at zero.

Comment: I just studied up further and this was the method suggested for finding a proof that such "functions",  a(x) and b(x) don't exist. And indeed they don't exist.

Comment: Hey, I have a small doubt, why did you write the coefficient of y'' to be 1. I mean what if you take to the denominator to be the coefficient of y'', won't it be a second-order, linear, homogeneous ODE?